# Pattern to use when only a few functions have a dependency?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a class like this:

```
class X {
  X (databaseconn, httpclient) {
    this.httpclient = httpclient
    this.databaseconn = databaseconn
  }

  public func1(a, b) {
    // ...
  }

  public func2(x, y, z) {
    // ...
  }

  // ...

  public funcN(p, q, r) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

There are very few methods in the class that operate on the injected `httpclient` (either directly or through some other method). Creating and injecting it, therefore, seems unnecessary and wasteful to me.

What pattern should be followed when there is a rarely used dependency such as the `httpclient` in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a class meets the single responsibility principle?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154723/how-to-determine-if-a-class-meets-the-single-responsibility-principle)

Comment: You mean object-oriented design patterns? Depends on the case, your question is very abstract, whats the concern of the class?

Comment: Why not simply create a base class that *does not have* an `httpclient`? Searching for a pattern here seems a bit overkill to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide if `httpclient` is a dependency of the object or of the methods - and this depends on the **class**.

For example - let's say you have a `Message` class that needs `smtpclient` for it's `send` method. Let's also say we have a `MailReceiver` class that checks for new emails and needs `smtpclient` for it's `poll` method. Both classes' other methods don't need `smtpclient`. Is it a dependency of the object or of the methods?

In `Message`'s case, it's a dependency of the method. An email message is an email message even before you send it, and you may want to send it via multiple SMTP clients. So you don't pass `smtpclient` to the c'tor - you pass it directly to the `send` method.

For `MailReceiver`, on the other hand, it's a dependency of the object. A mail receiver needs to receive the mails from somewhere. So you pass `smtpclient` to the c'tor, and `poll` just has it.

Don't think in terms of "unnecessary" and "wasteful" - think what makes sense for the object model.