# Does putting AddCustomerData, GetAllCustomers and GetCustomerByID in one class violate SRP?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, solid, single-responsibility

I am little bit confused about whether I can put all below functions to one class or if I should split into more classes.
I think `GetCustomerByID` and `AddCustomerData` got different responsibilites but on the other hand I think it's the same responsibility. Please help me by clearing the concept what is SRP in following code.

```
public class CustomerHelper
{
    NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();

    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        return db.Customers.ToList();
    }

    public Customer GetCustomerByID(string customerid)
    {
        return db.Customers.Find(customerid);
    }

    public int AddCustomerData(Customer customer)
    {  
        db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        return customer.CustID;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can think of all of those methods having the "Manage Customer" responsibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a class meets the single responsibility principle?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154723/how-to-determine-if-a-class-meets-the-single-responsibility-principle)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the `GetAllCustomers`, `GetCustomerByID` and `AddCustomerData` functions can co-exist in one class without violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

Each of those functions does something that is related to the persistent storage of `Customer` objects, either retrieving such objects or storing them.
The single responsibility of the `CustomerHelper` class is "the persistent storage of Customer objects".

As a side note, a more conventional name for `CustomerHelper` would have been `CustomerRepository`.