# Single responsibility of Program class in C#

Tags: c#, architecture, .net

I do not follow SOLID strictly in general, but I do try making sure to separate responsibilities of my classes.

I was developing a small app with a Windows service powered by Topshelf and realized that I don't quite understand what should `Program` class do. Obviously I could probably shove most code into `Main`, but what is the reasonable amount of responsibilities that this class should have?

My options:

1. `Program` is just a housing for `Main`, which is just an entry-point for the app, and the rest of the code should be moved to a separate class.
2. `Main` should only be a composition root of the application, with a separate class handling general workflow (like graceful shutdowns on exceptions) and calls to business logic.
3. Another static method in `Program` should be handling the composition and calls to application class.
4. `Program` is the application workflow class and its nonstatic methods call business logic, while `Main` is an entry point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a class meets the single responsibility principle?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154723/how-to-determine-if-a-class-meets-the-single-responsibility-principle)

Comment: Any of those 4 options could be the right one for you.    The prerequisite to being able to follow SRP is to understand what your objectives are in the first place.  i.e. what is it that you're trying to achieve?    The SOLID principles, and especially SRP are intended to help steer you towards a design which meets the KISS and DRY principles, and also makes code easy to test.    Start out by thinking about how you will write your tests and then choose the option which lets you have gets you as close to KISS/DRY as possible.  The right choice of those 4 is the one which minimises complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach I take is to view `Program.Main` as untestable without running the app. Therefore, it (and the rest of `Program`) should only have responsibility for setting up the runtime composition and kicking things off. Everything else should exist in other classes so that they can be tested, individually or in other, non-runtime, compositions as needed.

If the composition is simple, put it in `Main`, otherwise have `Main` call a private composition method (or even another class if really complex) to perform that composition.

So I'd opt for a mixture of options 2 and 3, depending on size. Option 1 is also worth considering when composition occurs in another class. Just don't do option 4 in my view.